# Leiningen Not Running JUnit Test Cases

Tags: junit, clojure, leiningen

I support a mixed Clojure/Java application that uses Leiningen for build. Everything works correctly except that `lein test` is not executing any Java JUnit test cases. The Clojure test cases are run, however. Is this possible using Leiningen?

I understand that the clojure-maven-plugin might work for this use case, but I was hoping  to not rewrite the build.

I am using this structure:

```
└── test
    ├── clj
    │   └── example_service
    └── java
        └── com
            └── example
                └── service
```

I have this in my project.clj Leiningen build:

```
  :source-paths ["src/clj"]
  :java-source-paths ["src/java"]
  :test-paths ["test/clj"]
```

I do not see a `:java-test-paths ["test/java"]` option available in Leiningen which makes me think this is not possible. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: A simple Google search for `leiningen junit` yields [lein-junit](https://github.com/lein-junit/lein-junit). Have you tried this?

Comment: This looks promising and I will try it out.

Comment: lein-junit plugin is what I need. However, it does not support JUnit 5 (Jupiter). I am still trying to make this work, but hoping there is another solution out there.

Comment: lein-junit use ant junit 4 task. One workaround is to use the junit4 to run junit5 (but this is deprecated and limited) https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner